# Select2 doesn't show result from AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

why my select2 object when filtering always show 'No Results Found' but when i checked on Inspect Network on Google Chrome there's response from it. I'm using select2 ver. 4.0.6-rc.1

[image: Select2]

here's my code to create select2 obj :

```
<div class="form-group" id="divjualcust">
    <label>Customer</label>
    <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="customer" id="jualcust" style="width:100%"></select>
    <label id="lblerrjual" style="display:none"><i>*sudah terdaftar</i></label>
</div>
```

javascript codes :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#jualcust").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "controller/customer_list.php",
            dataType: "json",
            type:"GET",
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    search: params.term
                }
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                // alter the remote JSON data
                return {
                    results: $.map(data.items, function (item) {
                      return {
                        id:item.id,
                        text:item.text
                      }
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: false
        },
        minimumInputLength: 3,
    });
```

and here's the function on my `controller/customer_list.php` :

```
function getCustList($search) {
    //declare var public
    $cn=new Database();
    $cust=array();
    $row=$cn->getAll("select cust_id, concat(cust_kode,' - ',cust_nama) as custnama from t_customer 
                      where concat(cust_kode,' - ',cust_nama) like '%$search%' order by concat(cust_kode,' - ',cust_nama)");
    if (is_array($row)) {
        foreach ($row as $dt) {
            $id=$dt["cust_id"];
            $text=$dt["custnama"];
            $cust[]=array("id"=>$id,"text"=>$text);
        }
        echo json_encode($cust);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting headers from PHP to be `header('Content-Type: application/json');`?

Comment: @Justinas still no luck.

Comment: Does network tab or console tab in DevTools shows any errors/warnings? I think problem is that you output plain array, but in JS you expect to be `items` key first. Try changing `results: $.map(data.items...` to `results: data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a `items` array so you need to loop only over `data`

```
results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                      return {
                        id:item.id,
                        text:item.text
                      }
                    })
```